# Jquery: Как сложить 2 числа с текстом?

Tags: php, jquery

Пример: "1000 грн." + "500 грн.". Должно получится "1500 грн.", но вместо этого нет ничего. Сумма отображается только при "1000" + "500".

Comment: Оно и логично .

Comment: А как быть если в будет "1000 грн" + "500 гривен"?

Comment: Отделить нечисловые хвосты. Сравнить, убедиться,что они совпадают (и не придётся складывать крокодилов с сапогами). То, что осталось - сложить. Довесить хвост. Profit.

Comment: а вам на php нужно или на js?

Answer (score 1):

`parseInt` конвертирует в число начальную часть строки, если это возможно:

```js
var a = parseInt("1000 грн.");
var b = parseInt("500 грн.");
var c = a + b;
console.log(a, b, c);
```

Comment: Не соответствует запросу =)  **Должно получится "1500 грн."**

Comment: Ну и решение не универсальное, к слову.

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков Посмотрите на иконку с именем автора вопроса. Репутация 1 и "Новый участник" Вам что-нибудь говорят? Автор еще не научился как следует формулировать "запросы". Постепенно научится.

Comment: Поэтому под вопросом автора есть комментарий с вопросом к автору что он хочет получать при сложении текста, ибо про числа понятно, про текст - нет =) может быть что ключевое это сложение только одинаковой валюты, или вообще конвертация валюты =)